# Kafka Streams (KStream-Ktable) Join partially joined

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When (left) joining a Kstream with a Ktable some messages produce join pairs which do not have a matching Ktable message.

But when taking a look at the topics this should have succeeded:

KStream message:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|       Key  | Timestamp  | Partition  | Offset        |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| "1000002547"  | 2020-12-11T12:18:47.67Z  |  9 | 1249 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

KTable messages:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|     Key  | Timestamp  | Partition  | Offset      |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| "2120103"  | 2020-11-27T12:14:23.488Z  |  4 | 27 |
| "2120103" |  2020-12-08T07:59:38.066Z |  4 | 56  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Internal repartition topic:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|    Key  | Timestamp  | Partition  | Offset    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| "2120103" |  2020-12-11T12:18:47.67Z | 4  | 0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**Additional information:**

- all topics only have the clean up strategy compact
- joining is done on String values since all keys are string (see " " in tables)
- The timestamps show that the timestamps of the Ktable are smaller than the ones of the stream

As the example shows the Ktable message exists and the Kstream message was correctly repartitioned.

Comment: I am failing to follow up with the question. Left Joins: Emits an output for each record in the left or primary input source. If the other source does not have a value for a given key, it is set to null. can you share the code and the output?

Comment: My example tried to make clear that there is actually a matching value for the message but this did not get joined.